# Is there a way to make jayson npm JSON-RPC calls from within nest.js?

Tags: nestjs, json-rpc

I have looked at previous similar questions but nothing comes close, so I am hoping someone can help me here. I want to make a jayson npm JSON-RPC (with authentication in the request object) call from within a generic nest.js application to an external application.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to instance a jayson client and then use it, nothing more:

```
'use strict';

const jayson = require('./../..');

// create a client
const client = jayson.client.http({
  port: 3000
});

// invoke "add"
client.request('add', [1, 1], function(err, response) {
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log(response.result); // 2
});
```

If your question is however how to serve a jayson from nest.js, you can add the jayson server as a middleware, here is a dummy (typescript) example:

```
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  public configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer): void {
    const rpcTestServer: Server = new Server({
      test: (args, callback) => {
        callback(null, 'hello');
      },
    });

    consumer
      .apply(rpcTestServer.middleware())
      .forRoutes({ path: '*', method: RequestMethod.ALL });
  }
}
```